# htaccess isn't redirecting to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to create an htaccess file in the root directory that will also affect subdomain directories (the subdomain works from a directory in the root).

Firstly, will this work if I have one htaccess file in the root? (will it work for subdomains in browsers (as they are actually just directories from root?) ).

The problem that I'm having is that when I try to visit http://demo.example.com, instead of it redirecting to https://demo.example.com it just remains using http://. This also is the case when trying to view http://www.example.com (it doesn't redirect to https).

This is my entire htaccess file as it currently stands. It seems quite bloated to me. Is there a way I can just redirect everything to https, regardless of subdomain / root ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# redirect subdomain to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Also can you add your `VirtualHost` entries for main and sub domains in your question.

Comment: No I can't do this, these are on the web server...

Comment: We need more details to understand your setup. Shown rules work fine on my Apache but your vhost config might be different.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask my web host to see if they can give any idea as to why it's not working.

Comment: They're not willing to tell me that information. They also told me what I want to do can't be done, but they can provide a solid redirect from non-https to https. Not for a default subdomain if one isn't provided.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and https to main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# redirect everything to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Test it in a new browser or completely clear your browser cache before testing.